# How to change lambda content dynamically in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: lisp, elisp

I have two functions that return an anonymous function, and almost all the content in the functions are the same except for a few lines.

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (lambda (arg)
    (when (not (string-empty-p arg))
      (message "foo")
      (message arg))))

(defun bar ()
  (interactive)
  (lambda (arg)
    (when (not (string-empty-p arg))
      (message "bar")
      (message arg))))
```

Therefore, I created a function that received lists as argument and returned an anonymous function as follows:

```
(defun make-anonymous-func (&rest body)
  (interactive)
  (lambda (arg)
    `(when (not (string-empty-p arg))
      ,@body
      (message arg))))
```

However, when I executed the function returned by `make-anonymous-func`, the list in lambda was recognized as list literal and wasn't properly evaluated.

```
(funcall (make-anonymous-func '(message "foo")) "bar")
; ===> (when (not (string-empty-p arg)) (message "foo") (message arg))
```

Are there some good ways to make it work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A form like

```
`(when (not (string-empty-p arg))
      ,@body
      (message arg))
```

is equivalent to something like this:

```
(append '(when (not (string-empty-p arg)))
          body
          ((message arg))))
```

So your function can be rewritten like this:

```
(defun make-anonymous-func (&rest body)
  (lambda (arg)
    (append '(when (not (string-empty-p arg)))
            body
            `((message arg)))))
```

And I think it's now very clear why this can't work.  More generally, backquote forms provide a concise way of describing ways of constructing s-expressions by filling in templates, which is useful in macros, since s-expressions represent Lisp source code and macros are essentially functions whose values are source code, ad well as in other places where you want to construct s-expressions from templates.

(One horrible approach to do what you want is `eval` which evaluates source code.  There are many reasons why this is a very bad answer however, so I won't go into it here.)

The general way to do what you're after is to rely on lexical scope.  Conveniently elisp now *has* lexical scope, so you actually can do this.  The following two examples assume that `lexical-binding` is true.

First of all if you merely want to capture the value of some variable bindings then you can do this:

```
(defun make-anonymous-func (msg)
  (lambda (arg)
    (when (not (string-empty-p arg))
      (message msg)
      (message arg))))
```

The second approach is if you want the function to run some general code: the way to do this is to pass it a function to call:

```
(defun make-anonymous-func (f)
  (lambda (arg)
    (when (not (string-empty-p arg))
      (funcall f arg)
      (message arg))))
```

And now

```
(funcall (make-anonymous-func
          (lambda (m)
            (message "foo")
            (sit-for 1)))
         "x")
```

Will cause two messages to appear, but this time there will be a pause between them so you'll see the first.

A final possibility, if what you want to do is create a bunch of similar functions statically – at compile time or definition time rather than dynamically at runtime – is to use a macro.

```
(defmacro define-messaging-function (name args &rest forms)
  ;; elisp has no destructuring, so check
  (unless (and (listp args) (= (length args) 1)
               (symbolp (car args)))
    (error "bad arguments"))
  (let ((arg (car args)))
    `(defun ,name (,arg)
       (when (not (string-empty-p ,arg))
         ,@forms
         (message ,arg)))))
```

And now

```
(define-messaging-function foo (x)
  (message "foo"))
```

Defines `foo` as a function which, when called, will do what the function *returned* by your original `foo` did.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The third approach seems to work perfectly as expected. Thanks!!